# Передать в класс значение массива

Tags: php

Что есть? Файл config.php и db.php 
В файле config.php есть массив с параметрами для подключения к БД
$db['host'] = 'localhost';
$db['user'] = 'зверев сережка'; и так далее.

В файле db.php есть класс для работы с БД

Внимание! Вопрос! Как мне в этот класс передать значение массива $db? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Сделайте $db глобальным ^^

Comment: а без глобальности никак низя?

Comment: Можно передавать в конструктор класса при создании. В чём проблема?

Comment: лучше организуйте конфиг не как `$db['user']` а как `$config['db']['user']`

Comment: А потом при объявлении экземпляра класса в конструктор передавать массив $db = new DB($config['db']['user']); так? слишком "громадно" получается

Comment: используйте $db = new DB($config);

ну и вообще это по другому немного делается обычно...

Comment: Как? подскажииии))

Comment: Ну подскажиииииииииииииииииии)

Answer (score 2):

Примерный класс db

```
class DB {
    protected $_username;
    protected $_password;
    protected $_host;
    protected $_database;

    function __construct($dbConfig) {
        $this->_username = $dbConfig['username'];
        $this->_password = $dbConfig['password'];
        $this->_host = $dbConfig['host'];
        $this->_database = $dbConfig['database']
    }
}
```

В файле, где у тебя нужно инициализировать этот класс подключаешь `config.php`, если он еще не подключен.

Ну, и создаешь объект: $db = new DB($configDb);

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!